# How to generate web service proxy code with wsdl.exe that is serializable

Tags: c#, asp.net, serializable, wsdl.exe

I am using wsdl.exe to auto generate the web service proxy code from a huge wsdl file. I then take the .cs file it generates compile it to a dll and use it in my program to make web service calls.

The problem is that when using sql session state in my program I can not save the proxxy object to session state. I marked the main class in the wsdl.exe generated file serializable, but it doesnt matter since it inherits System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol which is not serializable?

Does anyone know of a way to have the autogenerated code work with session state?

Comment: Why does your application need to serialize the proxy instance itself?  Since this is a web service proxy; doesn't it simply have methods to return data transactionally and populate some data structure?  Is the data structure really what you want to serialize?

Comment: @Aros, I have the same question as Gurdas too. You are trying to serialize the proxy object itself or the data it carries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, you would serialize *state* (entities), not the WSDL service wrapper. Most code-gen since 2.0 will write files as `partial` classes, which means you can add a second code file to add things like attributes:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    [Serializable] partial class Customer {}
    [Serializable] partial class Order {}
    [Serializable] partial class Address {}
}
```

This is *combined* with the other half in the wsdl-generated types, and should make it usable from `BinaryFormatter` - however, *personally* I suspect that is a bad way to do it. Since you are using wsdl.exe, your types are already serializable via `XmlSerializer`. Instead of serializing them with `BinaryFormatter` (which is what will be used by default, and which is very brittle), consider serializing them via `XmlSerializer` to a `string` or a `byte[]`, and add *that* to session-state. This will work without extra code changes, and is a lot more robust as it avoids the multiple brittle points of `BinaryFormatter`.

For example:

```
static string SerializeXml<T>(T obj) where T : class
{
    if (obj == null) return null;
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(sw))
    {
        new XmlSerializer(typeof(T))
            .Serialize(xw, obj);
    }
    return sw.ToString();
}
static T DeserializeXml<T>(string xml) where T : class
{
    if (xml == null) return null;
    using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml)))
    {
        return (T)new XmlSerializer(typeof(T))
            .Deserialize(xr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed post and sample code, it put me on the right track. :)